# React setState error -> Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I continue to get the following error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {questionId, answer}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I realise it is quite a common error on here but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

```
const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0)    
const [selectedAnswer, setAnswer] = useState('')
const [savedAnswers, setSavedAnswers] = useState([])

const question = questions[currentQuestion]

const handleNextQuestion = () => {
    if(currentQuestion < questions.length - 1) {

        //create answer array item
        const answer = {questionId: question, answer: selectedAnswer};

        //add saved answer to array
        setSavedAnswers(savedAnswers => [...savedAnswers, answer])

        //go to next question
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)

        //clear next answer
        setAnswer('')
    }
}
return (
    <div className="section">
        <div className="container">
            <div className={styles.surveyContainer}>
                <h2 className="title is-2 has-text-centered">Feel</h2>

                <Progress 
                    total = {questions.length}
                    current = {currentQuestion + 1}
                />
                <Question 
                    question = {question.question}
                />
                <Answers
                    answers = {question}
                    selected = {selectedAnswer}
                    handleClick = {handleClick}
                />
            </div>
            <button className="button is-primary" onClick={handleNextQuestion}>Next</button>

            {selectedAnswer}Selected Answers
            {savedAnswers}Saved Answers
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your render function?

Comment: Sorry, added now :)

Comment: `{savedAnswers}Saved Answers` - savedAnswers is an array, right?

Comment: Yes array of saved answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the array of answers. Use the `questionId` for the react key.

```
savedAnswers.map(({ questionId, answer }) => (
  <div key={questionId}>{answer}</div>
));
```

Comment: One issue though, what if I want to print out the question ID as well. It throws an error when I do something like this:
  <div key={questionId}>QuestionID: {questionId}, AnswerID: {answer}</div>

Comment: @unicorn_surprise That appears to be correct syntax. What is the error?

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, question, answer_a, answer_b, answer_c}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @unicorn_surprise Is `question` an object instead of a primitive value?

Comment: Hmmm I have added a screenshot of my questions

Comment: @unicorn_surprise Yeah, `const question = questions[currentQuestion]` grabs one of those entire objects. You probably want to grab `question.question` to render, just like you do when you are asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happen when you let React render an Object but not a normal element.

Answer (score -1):

const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0])
define this as well

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "define this"? I also don't think you quoted the source verbatim, and there's a syntax error in what you did reproduce.